# How can I integrate PHPagination into my website?

Tags: php, html

I got the PHPagination script, from the official website, but I don't know how to integrate it.

I tried to copy the source of the demo.php file, from that website, which can be found by clicking on "Interactive Demo":
http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/msb-v13
and then add the code from "Get Code", which is the following:
http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/jau-435

But when I paste the php code into the demo.php page on my local computer,the PHP script is shown in plain text.

I tried to put the PHP code in the beggining of the code and at the end of it, none of the following options worked.

I am newbie to PHP, I used to know just HTML and CSS and don't know how to integrate this code, I need it as soon as possible and don't have time to learn PHP.

Thanks alot! :)

Answer (score 1):

Always run PHP code between `<?php` and `?>` tags. Otherwise it's not counted as PHP and will not render. You might need a server for that to work tough, in which I case I recommend WAMP (for Windows), LAMP (for Linux) and MAMP (for OS X).

Answer (score 0):

http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html

PHP won't run locally the way HTML will, at the very least you're going to have to install something like XAMPP and learn how to use it to set up a local server. Either that or do your testing on your live server.